# Unreal Engine 4 nDisplay second screen cannot render media texture

Tags: media-player, unreal-engine4

I am working on a project to display CG graphics using Unreal. The plan is to connect the dual screen to one computer and run the client on that computer. I started a project using the nDisplay template with Unreal Engine 4.26, but I have a problem.

Media Player only appears on the main screen. On the second screen I saw the white basic material where the video should be. 3D Mesh and particles render well on both screen but only media player didn't.

At first, I set up a material that uses Media Texture on the Plane mesh and then launched nDisplayLauncher. Plane looks good on the left screen, but looks white on the right screen.

After that, I drew a Media Texture on the Render Target. I also split the Media Player in two so that it appears on each screen.
I also tried displaying the video directly on the widget. But all the attempts are in vain, and the screen on the right still displays only a white image.

How can I get Media Player to appear on both screens with nDisplay?

This is the nDisplay config file(.cfg) I'm using. For testing purposes, I temporarily set the window size to 1280*720.

```
[info] version="26"

[cluster_node] id="node_left"   addr="127.0.0.1" window="wnd_left"   sound="true"  master="true"
[cluster_node] id="node_right"   addr="127.0.0.1" window="wnd_right"   sound="false"

[window] id="wnd_left"   fullscreen="false" WinX="-1920"    WinY="0"   ResX="1280" ResY="720" viewports="MainScreen"
[window] id="wnd_right"   fullscreen="false" WinX="0"    WinY="0" ResX="1280" ResY="720" viewports="RightScreen"

[viewport] id="MainScreen" x="0"  y="0"  width="1280" height="720" projection="proj_simple_left"
[viewport] id="RightScreen" x="0"  y="0" width="1280" height="720" projection="proj_simple_right"

[projection] id="proj_simple_left" type="picp_mesh"  screen="scr_Main"
[projection] id="proj_simple_right" type="picp_mesh" screen="scr_Right"

[camera] id="camera_static" loc="X=0,Y=0,Z=0"
```

This is the blueprint I set for the PICP Module. This blueprint actor attach as child on Camera Actor. If the execution flow connect reversed, the video would play on the right screen instead of the main screen.

[image: PICP set up blueprint.]